# Is there a way to improve if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this if statement on ReactJS but i think this might be improved and better. Also, i think switch statement would be the same so i really would like to know if there is another way.

```
  setCosmeticsall(res.data.data);
  if (type === "outfit") {
    setCosmeticsall([]); //reset data of array
    setCosmeticslength(); //reset results to 0
    setCosmeticsall(
      res.data.data
        .filter((items) => items.type.value === "outfit")
        .filter((itemsname) => itemsname.name.includes(search))
    ); // set data to a specific type 
    setCosmeticslength(cosmeticsall.length); //set amout of results to show
  } else if (type === "wrap") {
    setCosmeticsall([]);
    setCosmeticslength();
    setCosmeticsall(
      res.data.data
        .filter((items) => items.type.value === "wrap")
        .filter((itemsname) => itemsname.name.includes(search))
    );
    setCosmeticslength(cosmeticsall.length);
  } else if (type === "banner") {
    setCosmeticsall([]);
    setCosmeticslength();
    setCosmeticsall(
      res.data.data
        .filter((items) => items.type.value === "banner")
        .filter((itemsname) => itemsname.name.includes(search))
    );
    setCosmeticslength(cosmeticsall.length);
  } else if (type === "spray") {
    setCosmeticsall([]);
    setCosmeticslength();
    setCosmeticsall(
      res.data.data
        .filter((items) => items.type.value === "spray")
        .filter((itemsname) => itemsname.name.includes(search))
    );
    setCosmeticslength(cosmeticsall.length);
  } else if (type === "emoji") {
    setCosmeticsall([]);
    setCosmeticsall(
      res.data.data
        .filter((items) => items.type.value === "emoji")
        .filter((itemsname) => itemsname.name.includes(search))
    );
    setCosmeticslength(cosmeticsall.length);
  } else if (type === "pickaxe") {
    setCosmeticsall([]);
    setCosmeticslength();
    setCosmeticsall(
      res.data.data
        .filter((items) => items.type.value === "pickaxe")
        .filter((itemsname) => itemsname.name.includes(search))
    );
    setCosmeticslength(cosmeticsall.length);
  } else if (type === "glider") {
    setCosmeticsall([]);
    setCosmeticslength();
    setCosmeticsall(
      res.data.data
        .filter((items) => items.type.value === "glider")
        .filter((itemsname) => itemsname.name.includes(search))
    );
    setCosmeticslength(cosmeticsall.length);
  } else if (type === "loadingscreen") {
    setCosmeticsall([]);
    setCosmeticslength();
    setCosmeticsall(
      res.data.data
        .filter((items) => items.type.value === "loadingscreen")
        .filter((itemsname) => itemsname.name.includes(search))
    );
    setCosmeticslength(cosmeticsall.length);
  } else if (type === "emote") {
    setCosmeticsall([]);
    setCosmeticslength();
    setCosmeticsall(
      res.data.data
        .filter((items) => items.type.value === "emote")
        .filter((itemsname) => itemsname.name.includes(search))
    );
    setCosmeticslength(cosmeticsall.length);
  } else if (search.length > 0) {
    setCosmeticsall([]);
    setCosmeticslength();
    setCosmeticsall(
      res.data.data.filter((itemsname) => itemsname.name.includes(search))
    );
    setCosmeticslength(cosmeticsall.length);
  }
```

And this is my filter data where the if statement take action. Where Search variable means whats user has typed on the input search.

```
cosmeticsall.filter(type.value === "All" || type.value!=="All" ? (items) => items.type.value : (items)=> items.type.value === type).filter((itemsname) => itemsname.name.includes(search)).map()
```

Comment: Why don't you use ```switch``` case? and also you don't need so many if else here as you should try to DRY your code, use template string as ```items.type.value``` is only changing.

Comment: Why make the values empty if you're instantly gonna overwrite them?

Comment: Where does the variable type come from ?

Comment: You're calling identical code except for the `items.type.value` value, which in each case is identical to `type`, so: first validate `type`, and then if it's valid, use that for the assignment. Now you have only one block of code instead of the same block 20 times.

Comment: @Nikkkshit I would like a smaller code bro! Thats why.

Comment: @Reyno I thought i would gonna get some kind bug if i didnt empty them

Comment: @InfiniteLearner From the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to dry out your code.

```js
if (isValidType(type)) {
  setCosmeticsall([]); 
  setCosmeticslength(); 
  setCosmeticsall(
    res.data.data
      .filter((items) => items.type.value === type)
      .filter((itemsname) => itemsname.name.includes(search))
  );
  setCosmeticslength(cosmeticsall.length); //set amout of results to show
} else {
  // handle the case where "type" is a bad/unknown/undefined value
}
```